# C# - How to cancel a task after wait times out?

Tags: c#, .net, task

I am working on some proprietary code and am trying to cancel a task if it doesn't successfully complete after 60 seconds. Basically, I have two objects, lets say Object1 and Object2 that are instantiated and their .Run() methods are called by two separate tasks. I want Object 2 to cancel if it does not complete after 60 seconds while Object1 stays running.. I tried using .Dispose() but realized that only releases resources and does not actually cancel a task.

```
Object1 o1 = new Object1();
var o2 = new Object2();

var o2Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => o2.Run());
Task.Factory.StartNew((() => o1.Run()));

if(o2Task.Wait(60000))   // Should return True if completed within time
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task successfully complete");
}
else
{
    o2Task.Dispose();   // This is how I thought you would cancel it
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` use `Task.Run` also make use of `CancellationTokens` which has a time out, also make sure your run methods take the token as well, as `CancellationTokens` are cooperative meaning your run methods will need to cooperate with them

Comment: In addition to **TheGeneral's** fine points, unless your task is actively monitoring the `CancellationToken` for cancellation, the task **won't** magically end.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will try to implement these ideas tomorrow and see what happens

Comment: What do you mean by cancelling a task? 1) stop and leave it when timeout exceeds 2)stop and rollback when timeout exceeds. They are different.

Comment: @ChengChen Stop and leave it

Answer (score 0):

Use Task.Run() instead. The Run() method have several overloads. Depending on what your o2.Run() returns, here are some of them:

- `Run(Action, CancellationToken)`
- `Run(Func<Task>, CancellationToken)`
- `Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>, CancellationToken)`

Basically, what you are looking at here is the `CancellationToken`. 
`CancellationTokenSource` has this constructor: `CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan delay)` where `delay` is

> The time interval to wait before canceling this
>   CancellationTokenSource.

More info can be found via this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_TimeSpan_)

Here is the complete solution:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))) // See(the remark section): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_TimeSpan_
       {
           try
           {
               new Object2().Run(tokenSource.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // <- should throw OperationCanceledException 
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               throw;
           }
       }
   }
}  


class Object2
{
  public Task Run(CancellationToken token)
  {
      return Task.Run(() =>
      {
          // Do your logic in o2.Run()
          // Assume o2.Run() takes 70 seconds to finish
          Thread.Sleep(70000);
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      }, token);
  }

  public Task<T> Run<T>(CancellationToken token)
  {
      return Task.Run(() =>
      {
          // Do your logic in o2.Run()
          // Assume o2.Run() takes 70 seconds to finish
          Thread.Sleep(70000);
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          // you can return something else instead of default(T);
          return default(T);
      }, token);
  }
}



class Object1 {}
```